# How to algorithmically select the appropriate accounts from a tree of accounts

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, accounting

To create an accounting report (such as Income statement/Balance sheet/ Cash flow statement), certain accounts have to be considered, for an income statement we need to consider the revenue, depreciation, cogs, interest, tax,... and so on.

**My qestion is for an accounting software to generate the report, there is a critria/algorithm to use to pick the right group. How would this be approached?**

1. surely not enumerating all the possible accounts, since those will just be names, and can be any value,
2. Enumerating the the tree then? enumerating the right part of the chart of account tree? This implies some rigidity in the initial setup of the tree, making sure every new account falls somewhere in the current tree (Assets/Liabilities/EQuity/Income/Expense)?

For a report like the income statement this is more involved since the income related to operating activities has to be distinguished from investing and financing, can this be distinguished in software simply from examining the right part of the chart of account tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be distinguished in software simply from examining the right part of the chart of account tree

Comment: could you elaborate, say how to distinguish the operating income from investment income in the account tree? how does this logical separation get done?

Comment: Because that's how you've set up your chart of accounts. Operating income and investment income are different branches below the "income" node

Comment: So in accounting software, every logically separate unit that appears in some report has to have been separated out in  its own part of the account tree?

Comment: Its nothing to do with accounting software, specifically. Logically, all income and expenditure has to be assigned to an account and all accounts rollup through a hierarchy to a single point. How that hierarchy is defined (the CoA) is up to the company/division/business unit. If the report needs to include different nodes on the hierarchy then that's fine - for example a "profit" report would be made up of "income" minus "expenditure", different nodes on the CoA

Comment: Probably what i should have said is things that affect a particular report need to be encapsulated in an identifiable place, so everything that is income needs to be under the income node, everything thats an expense should be under the expense node, and when computing things, you can total everthing under the income vs everything under expense.